# C# script task in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl

```C#
try
{
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\filepath\format");
    foreach (var f in d.GetFiles("*.csv"))
    {
        File.Copy(f.FullName.ToString(), @"filepath\out\", true);
    };

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

When i am trying the above script, i am getting the below error message

> File.Copy error - C# - IOException The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: i think that you got a good answer. Why ignoring it? if it solve your issue just accept it by [clicking on the mark on the left side of the answer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy to a file rather than a folder. The following will work:

```
try
{
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\filepath\format");
    foreach (var f in d.GetFiles("*.csv"))
    {
        File.Copy(f.FullName.ToString(), @"filepath\out\" + Path.GetFileName(f.FullName), true);
    };

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```